# How to make a Java program start itself repeatedly

Tags: java, runtime

I want this program to keep starting up new instances of itself. This program serves no real function, I was just curious. I was able to get it to find its own file path, but when I use a Runtime class and execute it using that file path, nothing happens. I also tried using a ProcessBuilder, but still nothing happened. I made sure to build it into a jar and execute it, because I know that it wouldn't work if I ran it in the editor.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Started");

        CodeSource codeSource = Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
        File jarFile = new File(codeSource.getLocation().toURI().getPath());

        System.out.println("File: " + jarFile.toURI().toString());

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(("java -jar "+jarFile.toURI().toString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the URI of your file? And does it work when you run it that way on the command line?

Comment: Perhaps [Java Threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Where do you think the output of the subprocess goes? The `println()` calls are sending the text back to the initiating process, which doesn't listen for it.

Comment: You could run another method through the main class. Instead of starting an entirely new instance, you could start a new thread and call the method.

Answer (score 2):

This class will restart itself `MAX` times:

```
public class Test {

    private static final int MAX =3;
    private static int counter = 0;

    Test(){
        reStart();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       new Test();
    }

    private void reStart() {
        if(counter++ < MAX){
            System.out.println("run counter =" + counter);
            new Test();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I run `new [classname]` nothing happens.  I'm using this to create a new GUI copy in my program.

Comment: @BentheCoder post a question about it and include an [mre] to show the problem. Alert me to look at it by leaving a message here.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75300203/java-program-starts-a-copy-of-itself) is my post.

Comment: @BentheCoder  See my comment there